# Link on click triggers also div on click

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script>
$('.container').on('click', '.card', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
</script>
```

Thats the script, when you click on the div it basically flips

```
 <section class="container">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front"><img class="shadow" src="/docs/a14c3df2f48bc9d856cfb4b01da54a64.svg" width="90" height="90"><br>POLITIKWISSENSCHAFT</div>
    <div class="back">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bf1">Berufsfeld 1</a><br>
<a href="http://www.uni-goettingen.de/de/studieninteressierte%3a+2-f%c3%a4cher-b.a.+moderne+indienstudien/220280.html">Studieninteressierte</a>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is the HTML.

The problem is, when I click on the link inside the div, the div flips back around, which makes it not user friendly. When I click on the link inside the div I want the div NOT to flip, but only to flip when I click inside the div or outside the div (which is the case now, but it also flips when I click on the link inside the div)

This is the [live site preview](https://www.uni-goettingen.de/de/vorschau_d82845d86c476d71b3e67da4b3cfafbb/643284.html).

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check the click target and dismiss the click if needed. The code below will block the toggle if the user clicked an achor element, you may need to tweak it but I hope this illustrates the solution well enough

```
  <script>
    $('.container').on('click', '.card', function(e) {
       var l_target = $(e.target);
       if(l_target.is('a')){
          e.stopPtopagation();
          return;
       }
       $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').on('click', '.card', function() {
   $(".back > a ").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Try this